# How to implement spotlight like search in Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, algorithm, search, full-text-search

I need to enable the users to do a livesearch of the contents of a folder from my app. On OS X, I can do it by using the Spotlight APIs which have been exposed. Is there a way in which I can do it on Windows? Does Windows Search SDK help me accomplish this? As far as I know, Windows doesn't index the files until the user explicitly gives permission. So does that mean I've to index the files myself? Are there any open source libraries which do this? How can I go about implementing my own library? Too many questions, I know. I appreciate answers to any of them.

Comment: Have you done any research on the topic on your own?

Comment: Yes, but all the links I found pointed me to the way outlook mails are listed in Windows search which is not what I want to implement. I don't mind creating the index myself but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Also, I found this library [link](http://www.voidtols.com) which searches only the file names and not the content.

Comment: I'm just saying that you should mention everything you've done, so that we know that you tried and got nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search SDK is good, but can be switched off by user.
Also try Googel Desktop - do the same thing, but also expects user action on installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I decided to go with CLucene because I found it more reliable, easier to use and to have a much more active community than Windows Search. And of course I can use it on both Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Xapain](http://xapian.org/). CLucene development seems to have stagnated.